# AS3: Array Guidance

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, sorting

Ok so I'll start off with what I am trying to do here with an Array. So I have a grid of 1-59, Now the user gets to pick 5 numbers. When the user picks a number it goes into a box in the top corner of the screen. So what I am trying to make an Array for is a user selects a number it goes into the first box then the second number goes into the second one and so on.

I am still new to AS3 and I have been reading about Arrays, but I'm still stuck on how to do this or even start it. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you know you need five elements in the array, so:

```
private var m_arr:Array = new Array(5);
```

That'll get you an array with five elements, which can be filled later.

Next, it sounds like you need to keep track of which number gets picked first, which number gets picked second, and so on.  So let's make a place-holder and initialize it to 0:

```
private var m_iNextElement:int = 0;
```

Then whenever they select a number, just say:

```
m_arr[m_iNextElement] = theNumber;
m_iNextElement++;
```

As Fygo already mentioned, you could just do this instead:

```
private var m_arr:Array = new Array();
.
.
.
m_arr.push(number1);
.
.
.
m_arr.push(number2); // and so on
```

Whichever is better depends on the situation.  Last, you need to find some way to tie each element of the array to a graphical element of some sort.  There are many ways you could do this, but if you're using MXML, you could consider making the array bindable:

```
[Bindable]
private var m_arr:Array = new Array(5);
```

Then you could have in the MXML:

```
<local:Box id="box1" text="{m_arr[0]}" />
<local:Box id="box2" text="{m_arr[1]}" /> <!-- etc. -->
```

Comment: Thank you for the help this cleared some things up. But I got one quick thing, I have all 59 buttons as movie clips. The user needs to click five of them, is there an easier way to add an mouse event click to all of them so the array knows they were selected

Comment: If they're in MXML, you can just use `click="someFunction(movieClipX)"`, where `movieClicpX` is the `id` of the MovieClip.  Otherwise you could put them all in an Array or ArrayCollection, then say `for each (var mc:MovieClip in arrayOrArrayCollection) {mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, someFunction);}`  In that case, let `someFunction` use its argument's `target` property to identify which MovieClip just called it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums:Array = [];

//when the user picks whatever number, you call:
nums.push(the_number_that_the_user_selected);
```

Is that all you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Yeah I guess so but now how would i make it pop up in the appropriate box?

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript offers your basic index array

```
[]
```

and associative array

```
{}
```

as well as some fancier ones like [vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3a0f5f19124318fc87b-7fff.html). It sounds like you simply need to do something with an index array.

Check out this tutorial, it's all about shuffling arrays. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-randomly-shuffle-an-array-in-as3--active-8776